# Upload dSyms Issue with terminal command

Tags: ios, upload, crashlytics, google-fabric, dsym

I want to upload dSyms using the following command

```
/path/to/Fabric/upload-symbols -a <api-key> -p
<platform> /path/to/dSYMs
```

Firebase console command requires fabric `<api-key>` which is found in the fabric website which does not exists anymore.

how can I upload my dSyms?

Answer (score 0):

Firebaser here - If you're not using the legacy Fabric Crashlytics SDK and legacy upload-symbols binary, then you won't have an API key. Any apps not using the API key will be using the GoogleServices-Info.plist instead, and this shows you how: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=ios#upload-dsyms

`/path/to/pods/directory/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp /path/to/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /path/to/dSYMs`